# Sub-folder inside folder on desktop

Tags: vb.net, desktop, subdirectory, create-directory

I would like to create a sub-folder Y in a folder X which I already created on my desktop (see below).

```
Dim myFolder As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "X")
If (Not (System.IO.Directory.Exists(myFolder))) Then
     System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(myFolder)
End If
```

I think I should use: System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path), but what will be the path?

I don't know the syntax to use to create a folder "Y" inside the folder "X".

Maybe, path = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\X\", but nothing is created.

Comment: Hey - that looks solid - what happens as you're stepping through, debugging the code, examining the variables? Does something not seem right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier than you think: [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) will create all the directories required, so you could use:

```
Dim myFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "X", "Y")
Directory.CreateDirectory(myFolder)
```

Or if you are using the .NET Framework 1.1 which only allows two items in Path.Combine:

```
Dim rootFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "X")
Dim myFolder = Path.Combine(rootFolder, "Y")
Directory.CreateDirectory(myFolder)
```

It is always worth looking at the documentation as it often includes useful comments about some common uses for a method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I can't see in the documentation 2 strings "X" and "Y" at the end of the method as in your example and it does not work for me and gave me an error on string "Y" : "Too many arguments to 'Public Shared Function Combine(path1 as string, path2 as string) as string'. I probably don't understand everything in this MSDN documentation.

Comment: @JLuc01 Ah - are you using a very old version of Visual Studio? I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Probably, I am (VBnet 2008). But, see my answer below.

Comment: @JLuc01 Perhaps you have it set to use .NET Framework version 1.1, in which case you are missing quite a lot of functionality.

Comment: Yes. I will really need to update my VBnet version (System.Core Version 3.5). Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it. Just doing a double combination.

Thank you for your help.

JLuc01

```
        Dim Folder As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "X")
        Dim subFolder As String = IO.Path.Combine(Folder, "Y")
        If (Not (System.IO.Directory.Exists(subFolder))) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subFolder)
        End If
```

Comment: You don't need to check if the directory exists: it is not an error if it does.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Actually I think I have seen already this kind of comment in another thread. I will remove it.